# It's given that $\frac{dx}{dt}= x^2$ Rectify the ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It's given that $$\frac{dx}{dt}= x^2$$ Rectify the ODE using the transformations $T=t$ $X=X(t,x)$ such that it is transformed into $$\frac{dX}{dT} =0$$

What is rectification means in ODE.